# Which trucks transport raw materials to factories - those of the factories or trade depots?

Tags: simcity-2013

The tooltip for factory trucks only states that they transport the factory's finished goods, ie. a Processor Factory truck transports processors. However, the trade depot's truck tooltip only says that it transports import/export goods to and from the global market.

So which truck transports raw materials from trade depot to factories for production? I import all of my raw materials, so there are no mines, etc. Looking closely, there is a slight difference in the way the two trucks look, and it seems to be the factory's trucks that transport materials, but can anyone confirm that?

My factories often run low on resources so it would be useful to know, so I can only increase the number of useful trucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The Global Market always provides the truck. This is true whether you are importing from or exporting to the Global Market.
2. For deliveries within your city, the "delivering from" building is always the one whose truck is used.

In your example, the trade depot trucks are the ones that transport materials to your processor factory.

Answer (score 3):

Factory trucks deliver finished products.  These trucks do not pick up raw materials.

Trade building trucks deliver materials  **from the trade building** to where they are consumed (power or factory).

Global market trucks spawn at the city border and are not attached to a building  (import and export).

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to follow the trucks, for the same reason as your question.

- The trucks from the trade depot / depots transport the materials to the goods producing factories.
- The trucks from, let’s say, oil wells, transport crude oil to the depots, then the depot trucks transport the crude oil to the refinery.
- Then the refinery trucks transport plastic and fuel to the depots again.
  Then the region trucks arrives and picks up your good for cash and leave town!

A tip would be to see how much a building produces, and then add the equivalent amount of trucks based on the trucks load capacity.